# React Query access fetched data with filter in a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-query

In my home page I have two components:

```
<UserSearch />
<UserResults />
```

In `<UserSearch />`, I'm making the query with a filter stored in the state `text`, which is coming from a text input. Also, I'm initiating the fetch when the submit button is clicked.

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const {
    data: users,
    isLoading,
    refetch,
  } = useQuery(['users', text], () => searchUsers(text), {
    enabled: false,
  });
```

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    refetch();
    if (text === '') alert('Please enter something');
    console.log(users);
  };
```

I want to actually render the data in the other component `<UserResults />`.

How do I get the list of users with the filter `text` applied and display them in the sibling component?

Answer (score 1):

I think useQueriyClient in react-query will do what you want.
for example you want to refetch query in other component, you can simply do this :

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    refetch();
     queryClient.invalidateQueries('query Key')
    if (text === '') alert('Please enter something');
    console.log(users);
  };
```

and for filtering and setting query data you can do it in this way :

```
queryClient.setQueryData('query key', queryClient.getQueryData('query key').filter(item => item.name !== 'john doe'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should manage the state in your home component and update that state / consume that state from your child components.

You can do this with the use of props (pass what you need to the child components)

Something like this:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const {
    data: users,
    isLoading,
    refetch,
  } = useQuery(["users", text], () => searchUsers(text), {
    enabled: false, // you will need to enable this for the query to run
  });

  return (
    <>
      <UserSearch text={text} setText={setText} />
      <UserResults users={users} />
    </>
  );
};

const UserSearch = ({ text, setText }) => {
  // put your logic here to set the text via inputs / buttons etc.
  setText("set this to something else");
};

const UserResults = ({ users }) => {
  return <>{users}</>; // do something with users
};
```

Also you'll need to enable your `useQuery` call for it to make the call.